# Reading from two tables in android application

Tags: android, mysql

I just want to ask about reading data from two tables, the main and the temp table.
the main table is 'translate' and the temp is 'translate2'.

is this lines of code do the job or not?

```
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT LOWER(kata_indo) as kata_indo, LOWER (kata_tora) as kata_tora FROM translate WHERE LOWER(kata_indo) = ?", new String[] {temp[i]});
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT LOWER(kata_indo) as kata_indo, LOWER (kata_tora) as kata_tora FROM translate2 WHERE LOWER(kata_indo) = ?", new String[] {temp[i]});
        int countRow = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String specialChar = "";
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: how are the two tables related?does the temp table atleast have a field thats related to the main table? what is in the main table that you want to read that is not in the temp table?

Comment: @life-evader i want the data in main undisturbed.. so i want to add the data to the temp table.. and i want to read the data from both tables.. it is a dictionary application database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, It doesn't. you have filled your cursor twice. Which means the data from translate table will be replaced after running the second rawquery method. So if you want data from both tables you must have two cursors.

```
 cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT LOWER(kata_indo) as kata_indo, LOWER (kata_tora) as kata_tora FROM translate WHERE LOWER(kata_indo) = ?", new String[] {temp[i]});
 cursor2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT LOWER(kata_indo) as kata_indo, LOWER (kata_tora) as kata_tora FROM translate2 WHERE LOWER(kata_indo) = ?", new String[] {temp[i]});
```